# How to use jsonb[] field with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I have a legacy postgres database here. I did a reverse engineering to map the database to typeorm entities and a jsonb[] field went like:

`@Column('jsonb', { name: 'layout', nullable: true, array: true }) layout: object[] | null;`

the problem is that TypeOrm is trying to insert an malformed string on this:

`malformed array literal: "[{"w":10,"h":7,"x":0,"y":0,"i":"d8ebe106-2123-4067-8ec0-ee45e6d1e8f0","minW":4,"minH":5,"moved":false,"static":false,"widget":{"title":"My New Chart","colors":[],"yaxis":[],"fillOpacity":[],"strokeWidth":[],"isStacked":false,"type":"Chart"},"styles":{"borderStyle":"unset","borderWidth":1,"borderColor":"#000","borderRadius":0,"backgroundColor":"#ffffff"}},{"w":11,"h":7,"x":10,"y":0,"i":"3f5f7a77-4602-4863-825d-ae2c1557e23b","minW":4,"minH":5,"moved":false,"static":false,"widget":{"title":"My New Chart","colors":[],"yaxis":[],"fillOpacity":[],"strokeWidth":[],"isStacked":false,"type":"Chart"},"styles":{"borderStyle":"unset","borderWidth":1,"borderColor":"#000","borderRadius":0,"backgroundColor":"#ffffff"}}]"`

This is actually not how postgres expects the array to be inserted. I need some advice to get this jsonb[] field to work. I cant change the database structure though....